# whats this " => " really means in php?

Tags: php

I have seen that many explanations says this is kind of belonging to "*Associative Arrays*". And also I have seen that some explanations address this symbolic thing as "*Assignment operator*". So, I'm having some confusions on this "=" too. Some people called this "*double arrow*" so I searched that one and I have found the following part from the [Php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php)
it seams like this operator has deep story more than with the Associative arrays.

Please can someone explains me what exactly this operator means.

Thank you for your valuable time. And i appreciate that.

Based on your real time experience help me to understand what should I keep in my head about this operator which is valid for all usages in php.

Comment: _"Please can someone explains me what exactly this operator means"_ - That operator isn't anything on it's own. When using it with arrays, it's for assigning an index a value when you define the array. When using arrow functions, it's simply the syntax. Then when you use `foreach($array as $key => $value)`, it's more or less the oposite of when defining arrays, as it sets `$value` _from_ the array. So I guess the answer would be "it depends". I don't know if I've missed some use case, but there isn't anything specific about `=>` that isn't context specific, as far as I've ever heard/used/seen.